# Compare large tables issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

We have a mongodb and we have two tables i.e TableX (records 5 million) & TableY (records 45 million) ..both have one key SSNO ...we want to compare Table X based on the SSNO in TableY and update TableY flag accordingly but sometimes it reflects the results in 7-8 hours and sometimes it gets stuck forever. Need advise from experts how to make a quicker processing and the right method to use. Thanks

Comment: Can you please give your DB query?

Comment: I am comparing Table_Y XSSNO value with Table_X SSNO field.

Comment: Table_X "_id" : ObjectId("5dafda15804df0142456b1fb"), "SSNO" : "1234567890", "XBASIC" : "090000", "XNAME" : "Joseph Tucci", "XBF" : "Y", "current_status" : "Y", "old_status" : "N", "add_on" : ISODate("2019-10-23T04:41:57.747Z"), "status" : 1 } 
Table_Y "_id" : ObjectId("5dd22430e561f141c051f6df"), "XSR" : 168340, "XATY" : "2095007 / 1443521000701", "XNAME" : "DON CARLOS", "XSSNO" : "781021", "record_status" : 1, "addOn" : ISODate("2019-11-18T05:12:36.933Z") }